# Recursive enumeration of totally categorical structures

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, computability-theory

A theorem of Hrushovski [1] says that every totally categorical theory admits a finite axiomatization which may include certain "infinity axioms", called a *quasi-finite axiomatization*. In particular, there are countably many totally categorical structures. My question is the following.

> Is the set of quasi-finite axiomatizations of totally categorical theories recursively enumerable?

An answer to the following, weaker question would also satisfy me.

> Is there a recursively enumerable set of quasi-finite axiomatizations,  each of which either axiomatizes a totally categorical theory, or is inconsistent?

The property of admitting quasi-finite axiomatizations holds also for the class of ω-categorical, ω-stable theories [1], or more generally, the class of smoothly approximable structures [2]. In each case, one can ask the same questions as above. I am also interested in smaller classes, i.e., the class of ω-categorical, ω-stable theories parametrized by indiscernibles [3], or the class of structures which are interpretable in the pure set $(\mathbb N,=)$.

---

References.

[1] Ehud Hrushovski. Totally categorical structures . Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 313 (1989) 131-159.

[2] Gregory Cherlin and Ehud Hrushovski. Finite structures with few types.  Annals of Math Studies, Princeton University Press, Princeton, NJ, 2003.

[3] Alistair H. Lachlan. Structures coordinatized by indiscernible sets. Annals of Pure and Applied Logic, vol. 34(1987), pp. 245–273.